# PhoneGap: Unable to Create Android App using Terminal

Tags: android, cordova

I try to create an android app using PhoneGap on my Mac. But, I only can create the app (hello) and couldn't create the Android platform for it using `$ cordova platform add android` command.

The error message I get is: [Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: ]

The screenshot:

[image]

I try to [put the PATH in the bash profile file](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) using `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile` method, but it still didn't work.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

1. install android sdk in **/Applications** then rename the andoid sdk folder's name to **android_sdk**
2. create **.bash_profile** in this directory, **/Users/zulhilmizainudin**
3. open **.bash_profile** then type this command

   export PATH=/Applications/android_sdk/tools:$PATH

   export ANDROID="/Applications/android_sdk/tools"
4. Save **.bash_profile** file
5. type **android** command in your terminal

Comment: I got JAVA_HOME error after complete steps above. http://i.imgur.com/KUwrIoD.jpg
@Dato' Mohammad Nurdin